# Double self-referential model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Considering a modelling based on geneology, a single model is intended to have two sets of self-referential relationships with postgresql.

The 'parental line' is rather straightforward

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_gestator, class_name: 'Individual'
  belongs_to :parent_nongestator, class_name: 'Individual'
end

class Individual < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parent_gestators, foreign_key: :parent_gestator_id, class_name: 'Parent'
  has_many :parent_nongestators, foreign_key: :parent_nongestator_id, class_name: 'Parent'
  has_many :children, through: :parent_gestators
  has_many :children, through: :parent_nongestators
end
```

*note: the has_many relationship is established to allow multiple parents via blood or adoption lines.*

The query is 'how to establish the second self-reference, that of a spousal relationship'?. i.e. that of a union of two individuals, not linked by a parental (and thus sibling) relationship.
A couple of reasonings arrived at a very compact definition

```
class Individual < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :spouses, foreign_key: :spouse_id, class_name: 'Individual'
end
```

However, there is a nagging feeling this is incorrect/incomplete.  Is the above correct/sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like having an explicit parent class is somewhat unlucky, because it requires a being to be a record of both models, e.g. when it has parents and children. I would refactor the models to something like that:

```
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base

  class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'relationships'

    class ParentChild < Relationship
      belongs_to :parent,
                 class_name: 'Individual',
                 foreign_key: :individual_1_id
      belongs_to :child,
                 class_name: 'Individual',
                 foreign_key: :individual_2_id
    end

    class Marriage < Relationship
      belongs_to :spouse_1,
                 class_name: 'Individual',
                 foreign_key: :individual_1_id
      belongs_to :spouse_2,
                 class_name: 'Individual',
                 foreign_key: :individual_2_id
    end

  end

  def children
    children_relationships.map{ |rel| rel.child }
  end

  def children_relationships
    Relationship::ParentChild.where(parent: self)
  end

  def spouses
    spouse_relationships.map do |rel|
      rel.spouse_1 == self ? rel.spouse_2 : rel.spouse_1
    end
  end

  def spouse_relationships
    clause = "individual_1_id = #{self.id} OR individual_2_id = #{self.id}")
    Relationship::Marriage.where clause
  end

  def parent_relationships
    Relationship::ParentChild.where(child: self)
  end

  def parents
    parent_relationships.map{ |rel| rel.parent }
  end

end
```

This is "cleaner" in the sense that it uses only one model for all individuals and that it transfers the different roles they can take (child, parent, spouse) into the `Relationship` model. The latter is subclassed into relationship types like `Marriage` or `ParentChild` to inject meaning into a given relationship.

Furthermore, by allowing to craft a custom where clause for finding spouses, it solves the issue that nags you: there is no (easy way (that I know)) in Rails to define two alternative keys for has_many-relations. The issue is, that any individual may be stored as either part of a marriage.

Additionally, as the relationships are now full-blown models, it is so easy to extend them, e.g. to add attributes like birth of place, date of marriage, date of divorce and so on.

The downside of this solution is that the return values of method calls like `individual.children` is a standard ruby object (an `Array`) that lacks all the super powers of AR Associations. In-between i had found a solution for the children method, but I couldn't find any for the issue of an individual being either spouse 1 or 2 of a marriage. If you find a solution for that, please let me know!

The basic PSQL commands to produce the tables would be:

```
CREATE TABLE individuals(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name CHARACTER VARYING);
CREATE TABLE relationships(individual_1_id integer,
                           individual_2_id integer,
                           type character varying );
```

Then, usage is simple:

```
father = Individual.create(name: 'John')
=> #<Individual id: 7, name: "John"> 

mother = Individual.create(name: 'Jane')
=> #<Individual id: 8, name: "Jane">

Individual::Relationship::Marriage.create(spouse_1: father, spouse_2: mother)
=> #<Individual::Relationship::Marriage individual_1_id: 7, ...>

father.spouses
=> [#<Individual id: 8, name: "Jane">]

child_1 = Individual.create(name: 'Tom')
#<Individual id: 9, name: "Tom">

Individual::Relationship::ParentChild.create(parent: father, child: child_1)
Individual::Relationship::ParentChild.create(parent: mother, child: child_1)

child_1.parents
=> [#<Individual id: 7, name: "John">, #<Individual id: 8, name: "Jane">]
```

Of course, you can demodulize the classes if you want to. I have come to like nested classes because they convey meaning to `Relationship` and you can have other types of relationships between other entities without a clash of concepts on the top level namespace.

Another avenue to follow would be to replace these ugly `individual_1/2_id` keys by a full-blown 1:n relationship between `Marriage` and spouses, i.e. `Individual`s. That would open the door to three-party marriages and to Rails' sophisticated `accepts_nested_attributes_for` mechanic. I didn't have the time to follow this through, but if you can, please post your result!

I think from here, you can flesh it out further! Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: [lots of fodd-for-thought to unpack] I am not certain of the benefit of having nested classes vs two classes; the db table still remains unique. It may be a matter of preference. What I have issue with is the `belongs_to` subclass as it does not allow for many-to-many relations (think adoptions, uncertain parents...). The whole approach made me question the initial posit.  It may be better to have a Union class to handle a slew of edge cases (polygamy, 1-night stands, secret lives...) which would not be convenient populating the Individual class.

Comment: As for the `issue of an individual being either spouse 1 or 2 of a marriage` observation, it is my opinion that a union class would have the intent of being applied exclusively to a bloodline (2 individuals who have a m/f attribute), any additional individuals 'contributing' to that union would be a sub-class of the union.

Comment: @Jerome You're right, it is a question of taste how to structure your models and their relations. I just followed my preference when I tried to suggest a solution. What remains is the suggestion to model the relationships between individuals with full-blown classes instead of Rails magic methods like has_many. Your consideration of a `Union` class sounds reasonable to me. That said, I currently do not see what I could to help any further. Feel free to update the OP or add more comments. If you notify me, I'll be back and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not address the question above directly.

A couple or realizations came to the forefront while dealing with this issue.
a) [Andreas Gebhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089588/andreas-gebhard) has a good point regarding nested classes.  When dealing with inferred classes which are not data table objects - and particlarly when their meaning is almost totally linked to the main model, nesting makes better sense (I discovered this as I had gaps between the two which went unseen given the separation of documents)
b) the underlying logic was somewhat convoluted, but mainly not refelctive of reality.  Given this is geneology, there are biological parents (and possibly others), full stop.  Thus a main class, with its own table, would reference individuals.

```
belongs_to :biological_mother, foreign_key: :biological_mother_id, class_name: 'Individual'
belongs_to :biological_father, foreign_key: :biological_father_id, class_name: 'Individual'
```

(the biological union could then be augmented with parents-in-practice individuals)

Then the Individual class, having biological parents

```
belongs_to :union

has_many :children_of_father, foreign_key: :biological_father_id, class_name: 'Union'
has_many :children_of_mother, foreign_key: :biological_mother_id, class_name: 'Union'
```

multiple references to unions and descendants are succinctly defined as

```
def biological_unions
  Union.where('biological_father_id = ? OR biological_mother_id = ?', self.id, self.id).all
end

def children
  union_ids = Union.where('biological_father_id = ? OR biological_mother_id = ?', self.id, self.id).pluck(:id)
  children = Individual.where('union_id IN (?)', union_ids)
end
```

5 modelling statements, 2 methods.